# breaking up sencha architect 2 generated code

Tags: extjs

I want to break sencha architect 2 generated code into different classes 
What i want is declare a tabpanel in another class and use instantiated class in the following code.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

height: 430,
width: 748,
layout: {
    type: 'fit'
},
title: 'Add New Business Unit',
modal: true,

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                frame: true,
                activeTab: 0,
                items: [
                    {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. So instead of typing up an answer(I feel lazy today...), I just created a short screencast which I hope explains what your are trying to achieve. http://screencast.com/t/RhiMAreJBTwb